# Is "iptables-save" will reload iptable configuration?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I am little confused. I know that `iptables-save` command will help to take backup of iptables with `>` to a file. But will this command alone will reload iptable configuration. Sorry, I don't have a server to check this and I was unable to see any online reference.

Comment: "save" means save and no more. `iptables-restore` is the command to reload saved rules.

Comment: Alright. So this is for ALL flavors of Linux right? @ipor

Comment: There is ONE flavor of linux, http://www.kernel.org/

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it changes the question too much. If you have another question then just [ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [iptables-save](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables-save) command writes a series of iptables commands to a file such that the current state of the firewall can be saved. If you want to restore that state you can use the [iptables-restore](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables-restore) command.

Comment: Ok. I am able to get hold of a server. I was trying save iptables using `/etc/init.d/iptables save` or using `service` command. None of them help. Can you help me with the command?

Comment: Edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: `iptables-save` and `iptables save` are not the same command. Load up iptables into your favourite editor and read it - be educated.